# Get list of My Places from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, rss, kml

I'm making a website that has an embedded google map (iFrame) that has multiple place names on it that I set up in My Places. What I want is to be able to list the place names and addresses down the side of the map like it does in My Places.

Obviously I can just export the KML data of the map but I want the page to automatically update when a new place is added to the My Places map without having to export a new file.

If Google still supported RSS feeds I would probably use that, but the current API seems to need to rely on URL requests.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with an embedded map.  You can add a sidebar to a map from MyPlaces using the Google Maps API v3, a third party KML parser like geoxml3 and a proxy.

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fmsa%3D0%26msid%3D204048902337864904598.0004cc332e8034251c1db%26ie%3DUTF8%26ll%3D37.668046%2C-80.289717%26spn%3D1.959603%2C5.642338%26output%3Dkml)